tokenize multilple files python
I am currently trying to attempting to tokenize large text, however I have a lot of files in the directory that I want to tokenize as this is very time consuming to do 1 by 1.
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, pipeline
import torch


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("joeddav/distilbert-base-uncased-go-emotions-student")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("joeddav/distilbert-base-uncased-go-emotions-student")

txt="...."

words_input_dir = "/content/sample_data/"

for filename in os.listdir(words_input_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(filename, "r") as input_file:
            input_tokens = word_tokensize(input_file.read())

tokens = tokenizer.encode_plus(input_file.read(), add_special_tokens = False, return_tensors = 'pt')

print(len(tokens))

tokens
before I added the loop the original read
tokens = tokenizer.encode_plus(txt, add_special_tokens = False, return_tensors = 'pt')

Regards,
I tried to loop the tokens function however it appears to only be taking specific printed text.

If you have loop then you may have to keep all values on lists - instead of using single variables input_tokens and tokens.

you should run tokenizer.encode_plus inside loop - or you should first read all file, joine then to one string and later use this string in tokenizer.encode_plus() and word_tokensize()

I can't test it but as for me inside loop you should append input_file.read() to txt=
and after loop use tokenizer.encode_plus() and word_tokensize()
# --- before loop ---

txt = ""  # empty string at start

# --- loop ---

for filename in os.listdir(words_input_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(filename, "r") as input_file:
           txt += input_file.read() + "\n"  # append text from file

# --- after loop ---

input_tokens = word_tokensize(txt)

tokens = tokenizer.encode_plus(txt, add_special_tokens=False, return_tensors='pt')

print(len(tokens))

